# In PGAdmin SQL editor, why do I have to sometimes specify the database.tablename when within the same DB?

Tags: sql, database

This is something that has bugged me for many many years and have never asked.

Why is it that when writing SQL against a schema in a databases, whether it be Oracle, Postgres, MySQL or MSSQL I have to specify the database name and the table name? e.g.
SELECT id FROM mydb.mytable;
and other times as
SELECT id FROM mytable;

Is this some sort of configuration thing of the database I really would like to know why.

I am currently using the Postgres PGAdmin SQL Editor. I am selecting in the drop down the DB schema to utilize. When connecting to DB A I wont have to specify the DB in the query but when connecting to DB B I do have to specify the DB in the query. This is inconsistent and does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS's do not like ambiguity. So if you are in a context where you could be referring to multiple databases the DBMS will insist that you explicitly state what databases to use by specifying `database.table`. However if you are in a context where there is already an implicit database in use, that is no longer necessary and can be left out.

For a MySQL example:

If you log in to mysql and try to query mydb.mytable using `select * from mytable`, MySQL does not know what database to use, so the database is also needed. However if you were to run `use mydb` then queried `select * from mytable`. It is implied that you want to query mydb.mytable, so MySQL does not require the db be specified. But while 'use'ing mydb, you would have to specify the db if you wanted to query a table from any other database.

Comment: To clarify I am using the Postgres PGAdmin tool SQL editor where it has the drop down that allows me to select the connection to which database or establish a new db connection specifying the schema I wish to connect to. This is not through the command line. And in regards to what you state I completely agree that if I am specifying 'use mydb' that I shouldnt have to specify in the query to use the database which is what I would also expect from the SQL editor. If it has the schema selected then I should not have to specify the database in the SQL but in my environment I have to for 1 db

Comment: Hmm, your question seemed to be about the general idea, maybe you need to ask a question specific to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because of naming conflicts; you can have two schema  and in each schema a table with the same name. If you need to write a program that access the two table from a single database connection the db must understand on which table you are operating.
Example:

DB user A needs to read table T1 in its own schema but also table T1 created in the schema of DB user B; it must issue two differente query:

```
select * from T1
```

to read the data in the schema A and

```
select * from B.T1
```

to read the data in the schema B and to join the data (if the columns are equals on both tables):

```
select T1.*,B.T1.* from T1,B.T1 where T1.col1=B.T1.col1
```

The examples are valid for a DB connection of user A

Comment: The tables between the 2 schemas are completely different. There is no conflicts of names. The SQL editor window shows which DB I'm connected to so the question stands as to why is it that I must while within the same database connection specify the database that I'm already connected to in order to query a table within said database.

Comment: I use Postgres and Oracle every day and I never had to specify the schema name/ db name if the underlying tables are in the current schema. The only exception in Oracle is when you explictly change the current schema. The same happens with jdbc connections. This also applies for pgadmin. Check the db user of you connection (username filed in the properties tab of the connection)

Comment: I checked the properties for the connections to the individual schemas and the users are for each one are the owners of them. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: If on the left panel you have one connection for each user/schema of the single db i have no further suggestions, I have no problem with this configuration